# Printing graphemes given UTF-8 code units in shell

Tags: linux, shell, grep, utf-8

I have a file with a list of smileys code units, and I need another one with the 'grapheme representation' in order to feed those to a grep.
If I echo the code unit right in the shell it gets converted just fine:

```
echo $'\xF0\x9F\x98\x81'
```

But if I run a bulk echo it prints code units as if they were just a string

```
head emos_regex_utf8.lst | xargs -d '\n' -n1 echo
$'\xF0\x9F\x98\x81'
$'\xF0\x9F\x98\x82'
$'\xF0\x9F\x98\x83'
$'\xF0\x9F\x98\x84'
$'\xF0\x9F\x98\x85'
```

My goal is to run a grep on a bulk of files using the file with the graphemes as list of regex. Strictly speaking, I'm trying to run, e.g.:

```
cat ./20160711/* | jq '. | {text}' | grep -hEi -f graphemes.lst
```

/20160711/ contains a bunch of json files with a bunch of tweets, some of which got smileys on their texts, and some of which got smileys on other fields (e.g. "quoted"), that I want to disregard; so I need to extract the 'text' field with jq, which turns my javascript codepoints (from the .json files) into their grapheme representation. That's why I need the bytecodes.

I've written a test file, testreg.lst, which has one grapheme and one bytecode; they're distinct smileys and I'm sure I have a match for each on my tweets files:

```
testreg.lst:    
⛄
$'\xF0\x9F\x98\x81'
```

Running my code with this file returns the tweet containing the first entry, exactly what I want.

```
$ cat ./20160711/* | jq '. | {text}' | grep -hEi -f testreg.lst
  "text": "RT @C5N: ⛄ #MiAmanecer: Nieve en Caviahue, provincia de Neuquén | Temperatura máxima: 3°"
```

So my problem would be to turn the code units file to a graphemes file, which I expected to achieve with `cat emos_regex_utf8.lst | xargs -d '\n' -n1 echo > graphemes.lst`, given that `echo $'\xF0\x9F\x98\x81'` printed just what I needed, but it seems I'm doing something wrong.
btw, I'm running from Cygwin (uname: CYGWIN_NT-6.1)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$'...'` syntax isn't some magical "UTF-8 code unit" notation, and it's not `echo` that interprets it. **It's your shell** that does – that's the bash syntax for performing generic C-like backslash expansion, and what the system actually *runs* is `echo` .

Being a shell feature it's specific to command lines (and namely to *shell* command lines, not directly executed ones like xargs). Thus it's very unlikely that grep or other tools should automagically understand `$'...'` strings in a text file.

There are various ways to translate them manually, though. If you have a recent Perl version, try piping the file through:

```
| perl -pe 's/\$\x27(.*?)\x27/$1 =~ s@\\x([0-9A-F]{2})@chr hex $1@ger/ge'
```

or for older Perls:

```
| perl -pe 's/\$\x27(.*?)\x27/($tmp = $1) =~ s@\\x([0-9A-F]{2})@chr hex $1@ge; $tmp/ge'
```

---

That said, you could just tell jq to **not quote output in the first place**, first by selecting only the value rather than building a useless dict, then by using the `-r` (raw output) option:

```
cat tweets.json | jq -r .text
```

(If it's an array of tweets, use `.[].text`)

Comment: Those first two paragraphs clarified the whole thing. 
I worked it up with a python script